# HTML in React and ES6 Template Literal

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm passing some text to a component:

```
<Component 
 text={`text with <span style={{fontWeight:bold}}>${thisPart}</span> emphasized`}
/>
```

Although it certainly can't work but I guess it shows my intentions well. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass stringified HTML to a component because it opens XSS vulnerabilities.

If you **must** render html then you are required to use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

[source:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React's replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it's easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it's dangerous. For example:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks for the quick answer. Seems I should avoid using this, any idea how to simply make part of my text bold?

Comment: If the text does not come from user input, for example if it's hard coded, it's fine to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: @StanleyLuo here's a react component that does that for you https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words#usage

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for this. That is an anti-pattern.

```
<MyComponent>
 <span>text with</span>
 <strong>{thisPart}</strong>
 <span>emphasized</span>
</MyComponent>
```

The 2 `span` and 1 `strong` elements are accessible via the MyComponent `children` property

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>{this.props.children}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Would render

```
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>
    <span>text with</span>
    <strong>this part</strong>
    <span>emphasized</span>
  </p>
</div>
```